# Definition does not exist while creating lightning component dynamically

Tags: lightning-aura-components

While creating a lightning component dynamically getting error message

> Definition does not exist on the client for
>   descriptor:markup://c:ComponentName

but error is getting resolved by making attributes and component global, 
but i don't want to make my component global for some reasons.

Any help what to do ??

**My code :**
my component that i'm trying to create dynamically :

```
    <aura:component access="public">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute access="public" name="text" type="String" default=""/>
    {!v.text}
</aura:component>
```

my another component controller that is trying to create above component dynamically :

```
$A.createComponent("c:ComponentName", {
            'text' : 'my sample text'
        }, function(cmp, status, errorMessage) {
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var cmpBody = component.get("v.cmpBody");
                cmpBody.push(cmp);
                component.set("v.cmpBody", cmpBody);
            }
            if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {}
            if (status === "ERROR") {}
        });
```

my component attribute(cmpBody) is defined as follows :

```
<aura:attribute name="cmpBody" type="Aura.Component[]">
```

Comment: my component doesn't implements forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes or any other interface.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are using Aura.createcomponent? it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use namespace instead of c in $Lightning.use() and $Lightning.createComponent()